# Angularjs : $q.defer and asynchronous calls

Tags: angularjs

I am calling a $resource in a loop.
I want to call another $resource once all the calls in the loop are done.

I have searched and found about $q.defer, but I don't know how to apply it to my example :

```
for (var i=0; i<$scope.fraiss.length; i++){
   var frais = {};
   //copy some properties values of $scope.fraiss[i] in frais then persist frais
   FraisVente.save(frais)
}
MyNextService.query();
```

If anyone can help me on this...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `$q.all()`

From the angular docs:

> `all(promises);`
>   *Combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when all of the input promises are resolved.*

```
var promises = [];

for (var i=0; i<$scope.fraiss.length; i++){
 var frais = {};
 //copy some properties values of $scope.fraiss[i] in frais then persist frais
 promises.push(FraisVente.save(frais));
}

$q.all(promises).then(function() {
  MyNextService.query();
}
```